# Use x-editable to make a different element editable on click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, x-editable

Using the [x-editable dependency](https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/), I would like to make a different element editable when I click on an underlying image element.

```
<h4>Angular-xeditable Text (Bootstrap 3)</h4>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <h3 class="m-t-lg m-b-sm inline-block" id="line{{lineId}}" editable-text="headingLineContent.someText">{{ headingLineContent }}</h3><br>
    <a href="" class="disabled"><i class="fa fa-pencil pencil m-l-sm" ng-click="">{{ myImage }}</i></a>
</div>
```

Here is the JS:

```
var app = angular.module("app", ["xeditable"]);

app.run(function(editableOptions) {
  editableOptions.theme = 'bs3';
});

app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.headingLineContent = 'Some Text';
  $scope.myImage = 'MyImage.jpg';
});
```

And here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/emporio/h1zsw5nu/4/

So basically when I click the underlying element, the text above should become editable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the "Trigger Manually" article from here: http://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/#text-btn

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/koljada/h1zsw5nu/5/

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <p>
    <h3 class="m-t-lg m-b-sm inline-block" id="line{{lineId}}" editable-text="headingLineContent" e-form="textBtnForm">{{ headingLineContent }}</h3>
  </p>
  <p>
    <a href="" class="disabled" ng-click="textBtnForm.$show()" ng-hide="textBtnForm.$visible"><i class="fa fa-pencil pencil m-l-sm" ng-click="">{{ myImage }}</i></a>
  </p>
</div>
```